# How can I upload a PDF Firebase Storage?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-storage

I'm currently trying to get a PDF from the current view, then set it as a variable, which I can then upload to firebase storage, and get back the link.

I've already accomplished producing the PDF with the code below:

```
  func exportToPDF() {

      let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
      let outputFileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("SwiftUI.pdf")

      //Normal with
      let width: CGFloat = 8.5 * 72.0
      //Estimate the height of your view
      let height: CGFloat = 1000
      let charts = SmartSheet()

      let pdfVC = UIHostingController(rootView: charts)
      pdfVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)

      //Render the view behind all other views
      let rootVC = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController
      rootVC?.addChild(pdfVC)
      rootVC?.view.insertSubview(pdfVC.view, at: 0)

      //Render the PDF
    let pdfRenderer = UIGraphicsPDFRenderer(bounds: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 8.5 * 72.0, height: height))
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        do {
            try pdfRenderer.writePDF(to: outputFileURL, withActions: { (context) in
                context.beginPage()
                pdfVC.view.layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
            })
            print("wrote file to: \(outputFileURL.path)")
        } catch {
            print("Could not create PDF file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

      pdfVC.removeFromParent()
      pdfVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
  }
```

I just need to know how to upload it to firebase.

FYI - I've been able to upload UIImages using this code:

```
    func upload(image: UIImage) {
        // Create a storage reference
      let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("squawks/\(v.FirstName)-sqauwk.jpg")

        // Resize the image to 200px with a custom extension


        // Convert the image into JPEG and compress the quality to reduce its size
        let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2)

        // Change the content type to jpg. If you don't, it'll be saved as application/octet-stream type
        let metadata = StorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "\(v.FirstName)-sqauwk/jpg"

        // Upload the image
        if let data = data {
            storageRef.putData(data, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error while uploading file: ", error)
                }

                if let metadata = metadata {
                    print("Metadata: ", metadata)
                }
            }
        }
    }


    func getPhotoURL(completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
      // Create a reference to the file you want to download
      let starsRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("squawks/\(v.FirstName)-sqauwk.jpg")

      // Fetch the download URL
      starsRef.downloadURL { url, error in
        if let error = error {
          // Handle any errors
          print("error getting link: \(error)")
        } else {
          // Get the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'
          completion(url!.absoluteString)
        }
      }
    }

//On click of button:
            var strURL = ""
            upload(image: inputImage!) //inputImage is a UIImage
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
              getPhotoURL() { url in
                strURL = url
                print("STORAGE URL: \(strURL)")
              }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `upload` to

```
func upload(_ pdf: URL) {
   let data  = try! Data(contentsOf:pdf)
   let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("squawks/\(pdf.lastPathComponent)")
   // .... go on
```

Comment: Where am I getting the URL from when calling the function to fulfill the pdf variable?

Comment: Url supposed to be `outputFileURL` in your `exportToPDF` method